# Finding where a series converges pointwise and uniformly

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Consider

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x(1 - x)^{2n} $$

Where does the sum converge pointwise and uniformly?

I think $[0, 2)$ pointwise and $(0, 2)$ uniformly because it becomes a geometric series. Also the function to which it converges to needs to be continuous

Comment: What has the title to do with the question?

Answer (score 1):

You are correct about recognizing the geometric series converging pointwise on $[0,2)$.

For this series to converge uniformly on $(0,2)$ it is necessary that

$$\tag{*}\sup_{x \in (0,2)}\left|\sum_{n=N}^\infty x(1-x)^{2n}\right| \xrightarrow[N \to \infty]{}\ 0$$

However,

$$\left|\sum_{n=N}^\infty x(1-x)^{2n}\right| = x(1-x)^{2N}\sum_{n=0}^\infty (1-x)^{2n} = \frac{x(1-x)^{2N}}{1 - (1-x)^2} = \frac{(1-x)^{2N}}{2 - x},$$

and

$$\sup_{x \in (0,2)}\frac{(1-x)^{2N}}{2 - x} = +\infty$$

So the convergence is not uniform on $(0,2)$.  Noting that a problem arises due to behavior near $x = 2$ (and $x=0$), try on your own to determine and justify where convergence is uniform.

Comment: So it's uniform only at $0$?

Comment: @joseph:  No -- uniform convergence is relevant for a set of values.  So we say the series $\sum{n=1}^\infty f_n(x)$ converges uniformly to $S(x)$  for $x \in (a,b)$ if it converges pointwise and $|\sum_{n=1}^N f_n(x) - S(x)| < \epsilon$ when $N > N_0$ for ALL $x \in (a,b)$ where $N_0$ does NOT depend on $x$.  I just showed your series is not UC on $(0,2)$ but what about $(0,b]$ where $b < 2$?